# Passing data among more than two fragments

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment

I successfully implemented passing data from one fragment to another fragment using interface.

**MainActivity.java**

```
MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements InputTab.SendMessage, FollowingTab.SendMessage, FollowerTab.SendMessage, ProfileTab.SendMessage, UserSearchResultTab.SendMessage {

    private SectionsPageAdapter pageAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    public static String currentUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, new ProfileTab());

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        pageAdapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Sets up the ViewPager with the sections adapter

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager((viewPager));

    }

    // Adds fragments to SectionsPageAdapter and gives names for the corresponding tab

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new InputTab(), "Search");
        adapter.addFragment(new ProfileTab(), "Profile");
        adapter.addFragment(new GithubTab(), "Github Repos");
        adapter.addFragment(new FollowerTab(), "Followers");
        adapter.addFragment(new FollowingTab(), "Followings");
        adapter.addFragment(new UserSearchResultTab(), "test");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendDataToProfile(String message) {
        String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.container + ":" + 1;
        ProfileTab profile = (ProfileTab) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
        profile.displayReceivedData(message);
    }

    @Override
   public void sendDataToFollowers(String message) {
       String tag = "android:switcher:" + R.id.container + ":" + 3;
       FollowerTab follower = (FollowerTab) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
       follower.displayReceivedData(message);
   }
```

**interface sendMessage in InputTab.java**

```
// Interface for passing-in data to a different tab(fragment)
interface SendMessage {
    void sendDataToProfile(String message);

    //void sendDataToSearchResult(String message);
    void sendDataToResult(String message);
    //void sendDataToFollowing(String message);
}
```

**Receiver in ProfileTab.java**

```
// This is the part where it handles the data passed in from another fragment (tab)
protected void displayReceivedData(String message)
{
    fetchData(message);
}
```

This works fine, but the **problem is that it does not work for more than two fragments** e.g. From A -> B, C, D ...

I followed this specific tutorial : https://www.journaldev.com/14207/android-passing-data-between-fragments

So on my MainActivity.java, my sendDataToFollowers will give me an error while sendDataToProfile works fine. When I debugged it, the FollowerTab follower was null.

What would be a possible solution to make it work for more than two fragments?

Comment: @AmitVaghela But I am not sending the data to my Activity. I have to send the data to another fragment which is part of the TabLayout

Comment: you mean, when you change between tab you want to pass data right ?

Comment: Yes that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

**Tab 0**

```
getParent().getIntent().putExtra("key", "value");
```

**Tab 1**

```
String value = getParent().getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

**Another Way :**

You have to go back information to your fragment's activity. And your Activity dispatch information to its fragments :

```
// In fragment A
((ParentActivity)getActivity()).dispatchInformations("test");

// In ParentActivity
public void dispatchInformations(String mesg){
    fragmentB.sendMessage(mesg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to pass data between `ViewPager's fragments` is using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) and save the data to your `Activity`.

1. Using `EventBus` or `LocalBroadCastRecevier` to send data immediately to active `fragments` (usually there're 3 active fragments at once).

   `EventBust.getDefaut().sendData(YourDataObject);`
2. Save data in the activity, so that when the `fragment` is active, just pull saved data from activity in `onViewCreated`:

   `((YOurActivity)getActivity()).getSavedData();`